How to properly handle screenshot in pytest-html?
I am getting this error:

tests/test_homepage.py::test_homepage[Browser: chrome] Exception while screenshot creation: 'module' object is not callable

This is my html report



This is how I setup my conftest.py to add the fail screenshot in pytest-html. Appreciate your help everyone. I'm stuck this section. Thankyou
#conftest.py

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    outcome._result.description = item.function.__doc__
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report._testid = item.get_closest_marker("test_id").args[0]
    setattr(report, "duration_formatter", "%M:%S.%f")

    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("html")
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%H-%M-%S')    
    screen_file = ''
    extra = getattr(report, "extra", [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        try: 
            if report.failed and "browser" in item.funcargs:
                browser = item.funcargs["browser"]
                screenshot_dir = os.path('screenshots/')
                screenshot_dir.os.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
                screen_file = str(screenshot_dir / f"{slugify(item.nodeid)}{timestamp}.png")
                browser.screenshot(path=screen_file)
            xfail = hasattr(report, "wasxfail")
            if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):
                # add the screenshots to the html report
                extra.append(pytest_html.extras.png(screen_file))
            report.extra = extra
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception while screenshot creation: {}'.format(e))

#this is my test
@pytest.mark.test_id("3")
def test_homepage(browser):
    """Asserting the Title of the Login Page"""
    #Initiate the login
    try: 
        loginToApp = LoginPage(browser)
        loginToApp.login(username, password)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    
    #Verify title
    homepage = HomePage(browser)
    hompeage_Title = homepage.home_page() 
    assert 'Swag Labs' != hompeage_Title
    time.sleep(3)

